# LateInitializationError: Field '_database@29391942' has not been initialized

Tags: database, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, sqflite

I have a Flutter application that Inserts  data into a databass.
And It gets and displays data from the database.

But I got a **Late Initialization Error*.

I think the cause is in >

**static late Database _database;**

Error :

```
E/flutter ( 6700): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 
LateInitializationError: Field '_database@29391942' has not been initialized.
```

Code:

```
class ProductDBHelper{

  static final _databaseName = 'mydb.db';
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;


  static final _table_products = 'products';
  static late String path;

  ProductDBHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final ProductDBHelper instance = ProductDBHelper._privateConstructor();

  static late Database _database;


  //// Check whether the database created or not.
  Future get database async{

    if(_database != null) return _database;

    _database = await _initDatabase();
    print('Database : $_database');
    return _database;
    
  }
  //// Initialise database with local file path , db name.
  _initDatabase() async{
    
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    //// localstorage path/databasename.db
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path , _databaseName);
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: _databaseVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate);

  }
  //// on Create for creating database.
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async{

    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $_table_products(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, name TEXT, price TEXT, quantity INTEGER)');
  }

  static Future getFileData(){
    return getDatabasesPath().then((value)
    {
      return path = value;
    }
    );
  }

  Future insertProduct(Product product) async{

    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(
        _table_products, Product.toMap(product),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.ignore
    );
  }
```

Can Anyone advice me for solving this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are doing null check,

```dart
    if(_database != null) return _database;
```

you need to make datatype as nullable,
replace

```dart
  static late Database _database;
```

with

```dart
  static  Database? _database;
```

Comment: Error occured `E/Dart    ( 6700): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/object.h: 7827: error: Handle check failed: saw sentinel expected Instance
` *Lost Connection to Device*

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app

Comment: Error is gone thanks to you

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more on [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Can you find problem ? `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'` Its another errror from same project

Comment: could be `_databaseVersion` is needed to be string, you can try `static final _databaseVersion = "1";` check the place you re using `int`. it expect to be string